# Added a junit test file to the test package in eclipse but it will not run

Tags: java, junit4

I am using JUnit4 in an Eclipse IDE. I have one test file with 7 tests that run fine by selecting **Run As JUnit**.
I added another file for another set of tests.  I have 1 test in the file.
I believe I created the test correctly...
This the file / test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CloseSummaryOrCloseTrailerResponseTest {

    @InjectMocks
    XMLTransaction xmlTransaction;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenCloseSummaryResponseNoErrorExpectCorrectXmlMsgProduced ()
{
..code to run the test
}
}
```

When I select the file and chose 'Run As Junit' nothing happens.
What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
Sorry for the incomplete information...

The project tree is as follows:
    src/java/...source files
    src/test/com/javaserver/transaction/RequestTest.java
            /com/javaserver/transaction/ResponseTest.java

I can run the RequestTest file and all tests pass.
When I try to run the ResponseTest file, there was no output initially.
I restarted Eclipse and when I run the response test, I get the error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:     Cannot instantiate
>   @InjectMocks field named 'xmlTransaction' of type 'class...

I imported the XMLTransaction class. Yet it cannot be instantiated. 
I don't have a main method. I thought by adding **@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)** it runs the class.  It runs the other class file.

**UPDATE**
It looks like the object that I want to mock needs a 1 argument constructor.
The constructor would look like this:

```
XMLTransaction xmlTrans = new XMLTransaction(URL)
```

The URL is just a text string and not an actual URL.
But how do I instantiate the object?
If I put it under the @InjectMocks, I get the compile error:

> Default constructor cannot handle exception type Exception thrown by
>   implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

**UPDATE**
I need to use a PropertyManager class in order to create the XMLTransaction class. I use this code under the @InjectMocks to do that:

```
String wlUrl = PropertyManager.getInstance().getProperty(URL);
```

But then I get the error: 
Cannot handle Property exception.

**UPDATE**
I tried replacing @MockInjects to @Mock and used the init() to create the class:

```
 public final static String URL="WL_APPSERVER";  
    @Mock
    XMLTransaction xmlTransaction;  
    @Before
    public void initMocks() throws Exception {
        XMLTransaction xmlTransaction = new XMLTransaction(URL);
    }
```

I get the error:
Mockito cannot mock this class: class

> com.fedex.ground.tms.javaserver.dock.transaction.XMLTransaction.
>   Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes. Underlying
>   exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type

If I add a default constructor without an argument, I get the same error.
This is a public class and not final.

**UPDATE**
I solved the problem above by adding an instance of the PropertyManager.
This object needs a property file.
The error now is that it can't find the property file.
I have this now.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CloseSummaryOrCloseTrailerResponseTest {

     public final static String URL="WL_APPSERVER";
     public final static String PROP_FILE = "src/config/tms20.properties";

    @Mock
    XMLTransaction xmlTransaction; 

    @Mock
    PropertyManager propertyManager;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(new FileReader(new File(PROP_FILE)));
        propertyManager.getInstance(PROP_FILE);
        XMLTransaction xmlTransaction = new XMLTransaction(URL);
    }
```

What do I need to identify the property file?

Comment: Could you pls provide your project tree where these test files are located?

Comment: "Nothing happens". What would that mean? Where?

Comment: Where is the `public static void main(String[] args)`? What file is it being run from?

Comment: "The project tree is as follows: src/java/...source files src/test/com" - there's a missing java folder in src/test, com should be in it - e.g. src/test/java/com/...

Comment: The paths are consistent..I did not want to write the whole folder list.

Answer (score 0):

Place your Tests in hierarchy like this:

```
project
    src
        main
             java      // source files
             resources // xml, properties etc
        test
             java      // source files
             resources // xml, properties etc
```

Code must be something like this:

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class ExampleTest {

     @Mock
     private List list;

     @Test
     public void shouldDoSomething() {
         list.add(100);
     }
 }
```

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html

Comment: I did that. I get the error above (default constructor cannot handle exception). When I use the 1 parameter constructor, it uses a property manager class that has a property exception, I get an unhandled exception error.

Comment: Does this maybe helps u?
https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the constructor was calling a private method to initialize the class. Since Mockito can't deal with private methods, I solved the problem by using PowerMock.